# Javascript - Check for Hash, Ignore Analytics Code following

Tags: javascript, url, hash, analytics

We are adding a video to the home page of a site, and want to be able to automatically pop up the video (in a lightbox-style container) whenever the #video tag is present in the URL:

`http://www.domain.com#video`

The video needs to pop up if a link is clicked internally on the site (ie: `<a href="#video">`) and also if the hash is present in the URL on page load.

Easy enough to check for the hash in the URL using `window.location.hash` or when a link with the hash is clicked and fire the associated javascript function. That's working as expected without any issues.

However as this URL will be sent out in emails with Google Analytics code automatically added, the analytics code is appended to the end of the URL:

`http://www.domain.com#video?utm_source=...`

Because the analytics code will change with each email campaign, I can't do a simple Javascript `replace()` to ignore the analytics code.

How do I go about checking whether the hash is present in the URL, but ignore anything after a ? if present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the proper form of a URL to have the hash at the end after the query parameters?  Then, the location.hash variable will work properly and you won't need special code.  Your URL should look like this and then you can just directly use `location.hash` which will be `#video`:

http://www.domain.com?utm_source=xxx#video

I don't advise this as the solution (I think you ought to get the URLs fixed to be legal), but you can use this code to parse the hash value out of the URL even if it's in the illegal position:

```
var matches = window.location.href.match(/#(.*?)(\?|$)/);
if (matches) {
    var hash = matches[1];
}
```

This code extracts from the "#" to either end of string or "?" whichever comes first.  You can see it run on a bunch of test URLs here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HuqL7/.

Comment: It is, but the analytics code is added automatically to all URLs by the email software so it isn't really under my control.

Comment: I rather doubt it's going to work if it's added wrong.  I think you need to get it fixed it at the source.

Comment: @adnrw - I added code to my answer that does not rely on the behavior of the window.location.hash object that parses both legal and illegal URLs to get the hash value out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like that is working. I'll test with Google Analytics once it's ready to go to see if the tracking is recorded.

I doubt I can get it fixed at the source before this needs to go live, but I will raise it with the software provider (third party) as a bug if the analytics doesn't go through.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.hash.match(/[^?]*/)
```

Assuming the hash is always first, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a literal answer to your question, but there is a huge caveate) Technically, you can just test:

```
var h = window.location.hash;
var ind = h.indexOf( '?' );
var test = ind <0?h:h.substr(0, ind)
```

If you want Google Analytics to work, you may have problems `#`. The rule is that everything after a `#` is not sent to the server, which means that your Analytics may go out the window. You need to make sure that your hash is added after all of the Google stuff. If it is, then you won't need to worry about testing anything.

Comment: Right, I didn't know that. As mentioned above, the analytics code is added automatically by the email software, so there isn't much I can do.